# Hiding the password when typing into an Inno based setup

Tags: inno-setup, setup-deployment

I have a password field in my installer which deploys a .Net windows application.Installer uses Inno deployment script ,made in pascal.Issue is for password feild , i want to show a * character when user enters.Currently it shows the alphabets which user enters.Since i am not much into pascal scripting,so require a little help here.

Below is my code:

```
procedure InitializeWizard;

begin
     KeyPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
    'lisens validering', 'Tast inn lisens-id',
    'Vennligst oppgi din lisens-ID og klikk neste for å fortsette.');
     KeyPage.Add('lisens ID:', False);
     KeyPage.Add('bruker ID:', False);
     KeyPage.Add('passord:', False);

    booabort:=false;
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change this line

> ```
> KeyPage.Add('passord:', False);
> ```

to

> ```
> KeyPage.Add('passord:', True);
> ```

For more info check the inno setup [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputquerypage).